# change color of DataGrid row

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagrid, .net-2.0

I want to color entire rows of a `System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid` based on the content of one cell of the Row.
I couldn't find any way to do that, since there is no `.Rows`-Property of the DataGrid or a `.Row`-Property of the DataGridTextBoxColumn (or any similar).
Searching for solutions in the internet also didn't help me so far.
Switching to `DataGridView` is unfortunately not an option.

So the question remains: How can I change the color of a DataGrid row?

Comment: take a look at this, maybe it will help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms996485.aspx or this site http://www.codemag.com/article/0301071

Comment: You simply loop trough all the cells of the row and edit the background this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms996485.aspx) link (provided by @Monty) I was able to solve the problem.

You have to format every Cell on its own, so you have to hook up on the `SetCellFormat`-Event of every Column:

```
AddHandler column.SetCellFormat, AddressOf FormatGridRow
```

In the EventHandler you can check for example the cell value of another column of the same row and change the color of the current cell accordingly. When every cell of the row gets formatted this way, it seems like the row as a whole is formatted.

```
Private Sub FormatGridRow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridFormatCellEventArgs)
    Dim Cell As DataGridColumnStyle = sender
    Dim ColumnStyles As GridColumnStylesCollection = Cell.DataGridTableStyle.GridColumnStyles
    Dim columnIndex As Integer = ColumnStyles.IndexOf(ColumnStyles.Item("ColumnName"))

    If Cell.DataGridTableTableStyle.DataGrid(e.Row, columnIndex).ToString() = "SomeValue" Then
        e.BackBrush = New SolidBrush(Color.Red)  'this does only change the Cell`s background
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: glad to be of help.... and good luck to FC Augsburg too when they come to play Liverpool for the second leg in the Europa League ... from an Arsenal fan.... LOL