# Change The Color Of a Row in a DataGrid to the Color Red

Tags: vb.net, winforms, colors, datagrid

I have a datagrid populated with about 5 rows, and I need to change
the background color of one entire row to the color red.

This sounds easy, but I am hard pressed to find a way to do so...

I am using VB.Net with Winforms, and the option to switch to datagridview is a bit much for a color change but if that's the only option...

But was unable to use it correctly. Any ideas? If I need to be more descriptive please ask! Thank you.

Comment: You might want to specify if this is WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET or UWP.

Comment: I'm using winforms - I also updated the description

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this:

```
DataGridView1.Rows(x).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red'or whatever color you want, x is your row index
```

Comment: Third party, user control or custom control? Please don't shout when you are asking for help.

Comment: Oh, wait, this is a WPF control in a winform?

Comment: It is a Windows Form Class:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35556821/change-color-of-datagrid-row